# How to change the value of a key in HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

hello guys how can I change the value of a key in `HashMap`?

look at this please :

```
private static final Map<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode> M = new HashMap<>();

public static DefaultMutableTreeNode executeCommand(int command, String item1, String item2) {
      switch (command) {
        //...
        case CommandsList.CREATE_CHILD:
            String name = item1;
            M.put(name, new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name));
            //...
            return M.get(root);
        case CommandsList.CHANGE_NAME:
            String newName = item2;
            //
            //what should I do here to replace name with newName???
            //
            return M.get(root);
        //...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change the value of the key directly, but you can easily re-add the value under a new key like this:

```
    map.put(newkey, map.remove(oldkey));
```

Comment: What code did you add and how did it not work?  Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that "item1" variable being passed into the method is the key for the map, i.e. the old name. And now you want the map updated with "item2" which is the new name. If this is correct, you can remove the old name and then add the new one:

```
map.remove(item1);
map.put(item2, new DefaultMutableTreeNode(item2));
```

If instead it is the case, perhaps, that you just want to replace the value in the map located at item1 with the new name which is in the variable item2, then simply put again and the new item2 value will overwrite what is in the map at the key item1:

```
map.put(item1, new DefaultMutableTreeNode(item2));
```

I hope one of these is what you're after. Please let us know which one works, if any do, and mark as correct answer if so!

Comment: Then I really don't know what you're asking. That's what azurefrog's answer shows how to do but you said it doesn't work? Are you trying to retrieve the object found at the old key, then store it in position with the new key, and keep the old map entry along with the new map entry?

Comment: I really have no idea how to do that... :(((

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "keep it's [sic] position"?

Comment: So... you want the treenode to be in the map twice? once with the old key and once with the new key?

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thank you all for helping...finally the problem was solved :))

```
M.put(item2, M.remove(item1));
M.get(item2).setUserObject(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(item2));
```